# Object initialized in GCD block has methods executing in main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

My goal is to play a sequence of sounds with pauses between them in the background, without slowing down the main thread/gui.

When I run the code using the Time Profiler Instrument, I get the following. The AudioStateMachine init is dispatched to another thread with GCD, while AudioStateMachine's other methods run in the main thread. I need all of AudioStateMachine's methods to not run in main.

```
Running Time    Self        Symbol Name
87.0ms    8.7%  0.0     Main Thread  0x8531c
84.0ms    8.4%  0.0      start
84.0ms    8.4%  83.0          main
1.0ms    0.1%   0.0        -[AudioStateMachine audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:]
1.0ms    0.1%   1.0         -[AudioStateMachine play:]
1.0ms    0.1%   1.0      -[AudioStateMachine states]
1.0ms    0.1%   1.0      -[AudTabController viewDidLoad]
1.0ms    0.1%   1.0      instruments_notifier
4.0ms    0.4%   0.0     _dispatch_worker_thread2  0x85371
4.0ms    0.4%   1.0      __38-[ScreeningViewController viewDidLoad]_block_invoke
3.0ms    0.3%   0.0       -[AudioStateMachine init]
```

Code for the view controller that dispatches the audio background task:

```
controller.h
@interface ScreeningViewController : UIViewController {
    UIButton *okButton;
    UIProgressView *bar;
    AudioStateMachine *test;
}
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIButton *okButton;
@property(nonatomic, strong) UIProgressView *bar;

-(IBAction)okPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

controller.m

```
@implementation ScreeningViewController
@synthesize okButton;
@synthesize bar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    return self;
}

-(void)okPressed:(id) sender{
    NSLog(@"OK button pressed");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //kick off state machine
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        test = [[AudioStateMachine alloc] init];
    });
}
@end
```

And the AudioStateMachine.h:

```
@interface AudioStateMachine : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *player;
    NSArray *soundList;
    int index;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSArray *soundList;
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag;
- (id)init;
- (void)play:(int)i;
@end
```

And the .m:

```
@implementation AudioStateMachine
@synthesize player, soundList;

-(id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {
        soundList = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",nil];
        index = 0;
        [self play:index];
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"Error initializing AudioStateMachine");
    return self;
}

-(void) play:(int)i
{
    NSError *error;
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc]  initFileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[soundList objectAtIndex:i] ofType:@"wav"]] error:&error];
    player.delegate = self;
    [player prepareToPlay];
    [player play];
}
-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.5];
    if (index < soundList.count) {
        index++;
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1.0];
        [self play:index];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Reached end of sound list.");//reached end of queue
    }
}
@end
```

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please explain why you need to perform things in the background.

Comment: Call those methods from background thread. or use performSelector On BackGround

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads aren’t places where objects live - they are sequences of instructions executed. Creating an object on a thread only means that the CPU ran the code to set up the object as part of its executing that particular thread. It has no future impact on what thread any of that object's instance methods will run on.

If you need all of your object's work to be done on a background thread, you could implement all its methods to dispatch their work to a concurrent queue. As a contrived example:

```
- (void)aMethod
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
        // do all your method's work here…
    });
}
```

Also, sleeping the thread just to get a delay in playing the next track strikes me as the wrong approach. There are a number of less disruptive ways that are more friendly with the modern concurrency approaches, for example `dispatch_after()`.

Comment: that clears up my misunderstanding, thanks. I'll try using dispatch_after in lieu of sleeping the thread.